# How do I compare two perlin noise images?

Tags: image-processing, signal-processing, perlin-noise

Is it possible to tell if two perlin noise images have been generated by the same parameters? and if so how?

For example, both these images:

[image]

and

[image]

Have been generated by the same code, namely:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from sys import argv

def generate_perlin_noise_2d(shape, res):
    def f(t):
        return 6*t**5 - 15*t**4 + 10*t**3

    delta = (res[0] / shape[0], res[1] / shape[1])
    d = (shape[0] // res[0], shape[1] // res[1])
    grid = np.mgrid[0:res[0]:delta[0],0:res[1]:delta[1]].transpose(1, 2, 0) % 1
    # Gradients
    angles = 2*np.pi*np.random.rand(res[0]+1, res[1]+1)
    gradients = np.dstack((np.cos(angles), np.sin(angles)))
    g00 = gradients[0:-1,0:-1].repeat(d[0], 0).repeat(d[1], 1)
    g10 = gradients[1:,0:-1].repeat(d[0], 0).repeat(d[1], 1)
    g01 = gradients[0:-1,1:].repeat(d[0], 0).repeat(d[1], 1)
    g11 = gradients[1:,1:].repeat(d[0], 0).repeat(d[1], 1)
    # Ramps
    n00 = np.sum(grid * g00, 2)
    n10 = np.sum(np.dstack((grid[:,:,0]-1, grid[:,:,1])) * g10, 2)
    n01 = np.sum(np.dstack((grid[:,:,0], grid[:,:,1]-1)) * g01, 2)
    n11 = np.sum(np.dstack((grid[:,:,0]-1, grid[:,:,1]-1)) * g11, 2)
    # Interpolation
    t = f(grid)
    n0 = n00*(1-t[:,:,0]) + t[:,:,0]*n10
    n1 = n01*(1-t[:,:,0]) + t[:,:,0]*n11
    return np.sqrt(2)*((1-t[:,:,1])*n0 + t[:,:,1]*n1)


perlin = generate_perlin_noise_2d((1024, 1024), (64, 64))

cv2.imwrite(argv[-1], perlin * 256)
```

But they differ (because random).

Is there a way to estract statistics that would tell me how they've been generated?

Comment: I would get the FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) of the image and compare the frequency distributions of both images

Answer (score 1):

Since lower values for the resolution parameter generate a more gradual change in color from white to black there will be higher amounts of lower frequencies when the parameters are lower.
You could use the FFT of the image to get these frequencies and then find out if there are only low frequencies (low value for the res parameter) or a mix of low and high frequencies (high value for res parameter).

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sys import argv

def generate_perlin_noise_2d(shape, res):
    def f(t):
        return 6*t**5 - 15*t**4 + 10*t**3

    delta = (res[0] / shape[0], res[1] / shape[1])
    d = (shape[0] // res[0], shape[1] // res[1])
    grid = np.mgrid[0:res[0]:delta[0],0:res[1]:delta[1]].transpose(1, 2, 0) % 1
    # Gradients
    angles = 2*np.pi*np.random.rand(res[0]+1, res[1]+1)
    gradients = np.dstack((np.cos(angles), np.sin(angles)))
    g00 = gradients[0:-1,0:-1].repeat(d[0], 0).repeat(d[1], 1)
    g10 = gradients[1:,0:-1].repeat(d[0], 0).repeat(d[1], 1)
    g01 = gradients[0:-1,1:].repeat(d[0], 0).repeat(d[1], 1)
    g11 = gradients[1:,1:].repeat(d[0], 0).repeat(d[1], 1)
    # Ramps
    n00 = np.sum(grid * g00, 2)
    n10 = np.sum(np.dstack((grid[:,:,0]-1, grid[:,:,1])) * g10, 2)
    n01 = np.sum(np.dstack((grid[:,:,0], grid[:,:,1]-1)) * g01, 2)
    n11 = np.sum(np.dstack((grid[:,:,0]-1, grid[:,:,1]-1)) * g11, 2)
    # Interpolation
    t = f(grid)
    n0 = n00*(1-t[:,:,0]) + t[:,:,0]*n10
    n1 = n01*(1-t[:,:,0]) + t[:,:,0]*n11
    return np.sqrt(2)*((1-t[:,:,1])*n0 + t[:,:,1]*n1)


perlin1 = generate_perlin_noise_2d((1024, 1024), (64, 64))
perlin2 = generate_perlin_noise_2d((1024, 1024), (32, 32))
perlin3 = generate_perlin_noise_2d((1024, 1024), (1, 1))

fig, [[p1, p2, p3], [fftp1, fftp2, fftp3]] = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)

fig.set_size_inches(14, 8)
p1.imshow(perlin1, cmap='gray')
p2.imshow(perlin2, cmap='gray')
p3.imshow(perlin3, cmap='gray')

perlin1_fft = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(perlin1))
perlin2_fft = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(perlin2))
perlin3_fft = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(perlin3))

fftp1.imshow(np.log(np.abs(perlin1_fft)))
fftp2.imshow(np.log(np.abs(perlin2_fft)))
fftp3.imshow(np.log(np.abs(perlin3_fft)))

fig.show()
```

[image: FFT result]

If you want to get a rough estimation for the parameters you could:

- generate perlin images for some res parameters (4x4, 8x8, 16x16, etc) and compute the fft of those
- take your perlin image and compute the fft
- take your image's fft and compare it with each res parameter fft (using the norm or distances between distributions)
- take the parameter that has the least distance with your image fft

Comment: If you applied [a window function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) to the image before the FFT, you’d have a much easier time estimating the parameter of the Perlin noise.

Comment: @CrisLuengo could you please elaborate on that fopr a noobie?

Comment: @kevin-spaghetti - thanks a lot! Visually things are very clear. Forgive the begginner level question, but how do I convert from FFT to parameters?

Comment: @simone See that big cross in the FFT outputs? That is caused by the periodicity of the FFT -- you can imagine the input being repeated over and over again, tiling the plane. Where two of those copies join, you'll see a sharp transition. The sharp transition contains energy at all frequencies, which is represented as that cross. The window function tapers the signal towards the edges of the image, so when repeated there are no sharp transitions. With the window function, you can more easily examine the frequency content of the signal itself, without the artifacts.

Comment: @simone i don't know if there is a way of getting the exact parameters from the fft. I would generate the fft of some images with known res parameters and then compare the fft of your input image with those. By taking the parameters with less distance between the fft of the input and the fft of the generated image you can get an approximation of the parameters.